# PHP-Login and open a link

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple login system working against a MySql database with 3 columns:
-Username
-Password
-LinkToSite

If the login succeeds, the related LinkToSite (a hyperlink) should open in the browser after hitting the Submit button. How can I achieve this?

```
       <?php
$uname=$_POST['uname'];//username
$password=$_POST['password'];//password 
session_start();
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");//mysqli("localhost","username of database","password of database","database name")
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `login_info` WHERE `uname`='$uname' && `password`='$password'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
{
    echo "Login success";
    $_SESSION['log']=1;


}
else
{
    echo "please fill proper details";
    header("refresh:2;url=index.php");// it takes 2 sec to go index page
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you want a popup / new tab or a redirect?

Comment: Please, for the sake of  your users, hash your passwords.

Comment: ... and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any JS here , if you use you can get the result without page refresh . But your query and code is not proper due to which you are not getting the result . The following code will give you the result you want .

```
<?php

$uname=$_POST['uname'];//username
$password=$_POST['password'];//password 
//session_start(); //Don't need it here
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login_info WHERE uname='".$uname."'"); //Assuming the username to be unique in your database
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($password == $row['password']){
        echo "Login success";
        $_SESSION['log']=1;
        echo "<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location = '".$row['LinkToSite']."' ;}, 3000) ; </script>" ; //It takes 2 seconds to get re-directed to URL saved in database
    }
}
else{
    echo "please fill proper details";
    echo "<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location = 'index.php' ;}, 2000) ; </script>" ; //It takes 2 seconds to get re-directed to index page
}

?>
```

Comment: If you get your desired result then accept my answer .

Answer (score 0):

It's gonna be some javascript you have to write. something like

```
if($count==1)
{
    echo "Login success";
    $_SESSION['log']=1;
    echo "<body onpageload=\"dothis();\"></body>

    <script>function dothis(){
    window.location.replace(\"http://stackoverflow.com\");
    }</script>"

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to redefine the `<body>` and why not just close the PHP tags and write the HTML? It would look much cleaner.

Comment: according to what he provided, I didn't see body tags. and yes. if it works, it works. but the php is going to process before the html. so if you write the html inside of the php, you have more control over what happens

Comment: What do you mean by "more" control? As opposed to less control over *your* own code?

Comment: it's a conditional thing. you don't have to write what doesn't need to be written. you can save time and energy. (network)

Comment: By your philosophy wouldn't it make sense to miss out the function definition, the body tag and the `echo` and instead just close the PHP tags and keep the `window.location[...]` part?

Comment: returning to the philosophy of "if it works, it works"... yes :). I am far from expert. Sometimes, it is good to see things from different angles, especially when learning. The long-drawn out method like I have, or the quick script method like you or PHP web suggests will grant the same results.